# Strong uniqueness of the Ricci flow

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

In the paper ``[Strong uniqueness of the Ricci flow](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1246888488)", Chen proved the following strong uniqueness of the Ricci flow: let $g(t)$ be a smooth complete solution to the Ricci ﬂow on $\mathbb{R}^3$, with the canonical Euclidean metric $g_E$ as initial data, then we have $g(t)\equiv g_E$.

In the concluding remarks, he posted the question, asking whether  the strong uniqueness of the Ricci ﬂow hold on the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n\geq 4$?

I wonder if the above question is still open. If yes, are there any partial results in this direction? Also, what prevent Chen's proof in dimension $3$ from working in dimension $n\geq 4$?